# debezium SERVER app could not access file "decoderbufs" using postgres 11

Tags: postgresql, debezium

I'm trying to setup a debezium server with Postgres and AWS Kinesis using the following instructions: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/operations/debezium-server.html

and facing with the issue while executing `sh run.sh`:

```
io.debezium.DebeziumException: Creation of replication slot failed
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnectorTask.start(PostgresConnectorTask.java:143)
    at io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.start(BaseSourceTask.java:130)
    at io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine.run(EmbeddedEngine.java:759)
    at io.debezium.embedded.ConvertingEngineBuilder$2.run(ConvertingEngineBuilder.java:188)
    at io.debezium.server.DebeziumServer.lambda$start$1(DebeziumServer.java:147)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not access file "decoderbufs": No such file or directory
```

I found some solution to add `plugin.name=pgoutput` property inside configuration file for postgres connector, but it works only for Debezium Connector, not for Debezium Server app.

My Debezium Server `application.properties` file:

```
debezium.sink.type=kinesis
debezium.sink.kinesis.region=us-east-1
debezium.source.connector.class=io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector
debezium.source.offset.storage.file.filename=data/offsets.dat
debezium.source.offset.flush.interval.ms=0
debezium.source.database.hostname=localhost
debezium.source.database.port=5432
debezium.source.database.user=postgres
debezium.source.database.password=postgres
debezium.source.database.dbname=dbzm
debezium.source.database.server.name=debezium_cdc
debezium.source.schema.include.list=business_view
debezium.source.table.include.list=inventory
quarkus.log.console.json=false
debezium.snapshot.new.tables=parallel
```

Answer (score 0):

This variant of the property is working fine with Debezium Server:

`debezium.source.plugin.name=pgoutput`